# CSS sidebar with flexbox and static width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to implement a sidebar with static width and flexbox. I have two issues:

1. When the sidebar is closed, there is still space, and I don't understand where it comes from.
2. The `main` side isn't animated. It's been pushed without animation.

Here's my code:

```js
const aside = document.querySelector('aside');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  aside.classList.toggle('open');
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}

aside {
  background: hotpink;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0;
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.3, 1);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

aside.open {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <aside>
    Sidebar content
  </aside>
  <main>
    <button>Toggle</button>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio illum sed neque molestias nihil deserunt facilis voluptatibus recusandae vero necessitatibus quas id consectetur similique, architecto voluptates officia obcaecati, corporis dolor?
    </p>

  </main>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to animate margin instead.

```js
const aside = document.querySelector('aside');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  aside.classList.toggle('open');
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}

main {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.3, 1);
}

aside {
  background: hotpink;
  width:250px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left:-250px;
  transition: margin 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.3, 1);
}

aside.open {
  margin-left:0px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <aside>
    Sidebar content
  </aside>
  <main>
    <button>Toggle</button>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio illum sed neque molestias nihil deserunt facilis voluptatibus recusandae vero necessitatibus quas id consectetur similique, architecto voluptates officia obcaecati, corporis dolor?
    </p>

  </main>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works. Remove the current styles in thsese classes and try this:

```
aside {
    background: hotpink;
    width: 0px;
    transition: width 0.3s ease;
}

aside.open {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

If you really want to use flex itself: you can do like this

```
aside {
  background: hotpink;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0;
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.3, 1);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

aside.open {
 flex: 0 0 250px;
 transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

and also please give margin:0 to your body to remove margin.

Comment: It doesn't animate

Comment: Replace the display property with translate, I have edited the code. Please try

Answer (score 0):

add transform: translateX(-17%) to main

```
 main {
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex: 1;
    background: red;
    transform: translateX(-17%);
}
```